# how to round down numbers with a trailing zero in python

Tags: python, rounding, trailing

In excel, there is this formula:
=ROUNDDOWN(D28-D33-D34, -2) and I got the results ==> 166400. But the result without the Rounddown formulas is ==> 166468.50.
My question is how to get the same in python. When I do round (n, -2) I get ==> 166500.
Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is an implementation of the `ROUNDDOWN(x,n)` function in Python

```
def rounddown(x,n):
  return int(x// 10**n * 10**n)
  
print(rounddown(166468.50,1))   #166460
print(rounddown(166468.50,2))   #166400
print(rounddown(166468.50,3))   #166000
```

[**Update**]

A new version of the function `rounddown`, that can handle both *positive* and *negative* values of `n`. (simulate the ROUNDDOWN(x,n) found in Excel)

```
def rounddown(x,n):
  sign=1 if n>0 else 0              # getting the sign of n.
  n=abs(n)                          # getting the absolute value of n.
  p= 10**n                          # calculating p the nth power of 10.
  result= (x // p) * p + sign * p   # calculating result.
  return int( result ) 

# sample result

print(rounddown(166468.50,1))   #166470
print(rounddown(166468.50,2))   #166500
print(rounddown(166468.50,3))   #167000
print(rounddown(166468.50,0))   #166468
print(rounddown(166468.50,-1))  #166460
print(rounddown(166468.50,-2))  #166400
print(rounddown(166468.50,-3))  #166000
```